# What memory size can a R4i work with?

Tags: nintendo-ds

Years ago I purchased a [R4i](http://r4i-sdhc.com/downloade.asp) - SDHC v1.4.1. Its purpose is to put DS roms onto it so you can play the roms on an actual gameboy double screen. I never got around to using it until now which is when I discovered it does not have a mirco sd card in the package (got it from a 2nd hand store). As the roms and save files are small by today's standards (8mb for the game) I am concerned that using a 32 gig micro sd would not work. So before I go and buy a micro sd, I want to know what size it can actually work with.

Does anyone know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this article](http://www.nds-gear.com/history-nintendo-ds-r4-card/) and personal experience, the R4i SDHC model supports micro-sd cards up to 32GB in size.

> The new R4 SDHC card suddenly allowed capacities of up to 32GB to be used with an R4 card, making them much stronger devices for carrying many applications, games, music and movie files with you on the go

Comment: Thank you, I will try one since that appears to be the smallest sold in stores now.

Comment: I can confirm that a 32 gig micro sd card does work in the device. However I am sad to discover that I can only get DS games working from that port currently. The Advance game I was wanting to play isnt.